Samsung A20e hangs at booting
My relative's Samsung Galaxy A20e smartphone got stuck while reading SMS. I wanted to help him and pressed buttons for reset, but only a black screen appeared, now it gets stuck at booting. I can enter recovery mode but can't even do a factory reset because he doesn't know his Google email and password. But before that, I want to rescue all the data on the smartphone.
I tried Android Debug Bridge, but he hasn't activated USB debugging, so I'm only able to do adb sideload. I tried TWRP by sideload, doesn't work. I know Odin on Windows to install alternative custom ROM, but I'm now on Linux.
What software can I use to install custom ROM and TWRP, or what can I do to rescue the data on the smartphone - images, phone numbers, addresses? Do I have to unlock the bootloader before I can download a custom ROM?

Last line of your question. To install a custom ROM, you would need to unlock your bootloader, which would wipe all the data on your dad's phone//Same with factory-reset //As far as I know, there is no way you can access the data on the device

What I tried:

Created an account on https://sammobile.com, and downloaded the complete firmware for Samsung Galaxy A20e. BootLoader, AP, CP, CSC
Got Odin for Linux -
OFFICIAL Samsung Odin v4 1.2.1-dc05e3ea - For Linux
https://xdaforums.com/t/official-samsung-odin-v4-1-2-1-dc05e3ea-for-linux.4453423/#js-post-86977569
Pressed Volume Up and Volume Down button together to enter Download Mode, then pressed Volume Up one time to Continue in Download Mode
UDEV rule for recognition of smartphone
./odin4 -b BL* -a AP_XXXX.tar.md5 -c CP_XXXX.tar.md5 -s CSC_XXXX.tar.md5

Finally, the phone was reusable.
My mistake: I didn't flash HOME_CSC, I did flash normal CSC. I read that HOME_CSC would not clear the data of the smartphone.
